# protractor browser.pause() debugger exists Selenium

Tags: angularjs, debugging, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm using protractor 2.1.0 with webdriver. I've got a test which I want to debug so I put in a browser.pause() command.

```
 it 'allows deleting level versions', ->
    browser.get('/api#/costings')
    element(By.id("edit")).click()
    element(By.id("versions")).click()
    count=element.all(By.id("listing")).count()
    first=element.all(By.id("listing")).first()
    browser.pause()
    expect(element.all(By.id("listing")).count()).toEqual(parseInt(count) - 1)
```

This stopped my tests at that point opening up the WebDriver Debugger. As soon as I type a single character it shuts down Selenium. I'm trying to type in 'repl' to enter interactive mode.

```
------- WebDriver Debugger -------
Starting debugger agent.
Debugger listening on port 5858
 ready

press c to continue to the next webdriver command
press d to continue to the next debugger statement
type "repl" to enter interactive mode
type "exit" to break out of interactive mode
press ^C to exit

ControlFlow::1
| Frame::797
| | (pending) Task::796<Asynchronous test function: it()>
| | | Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
| | | Frame::805
| | | | (pending) Task::972<waiting for debugger to attach>
| | | | | Task: waiting for debugger to attach
| | | | |     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/map7/pais/spec/javascripts/protractor_specs/costings/edit_costing_spec.js.coffee:17:15)
| | | | | (active) Frame::1618
| | | | Task::986<Protractor.waitForAngular()>
| | | | | Task: Protractor.waitForAngular()
| | | | |     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/map7/pais/spec/javascripts/protractor_specs/costings/edit_costing_spec.js.coffee:18:51)
wd-debug> Attempting to shut down selenium nicely
15:00:43.732 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
15:00:43.733 INFO - Command request: shutDownSeleniumServer[, ] on session null
15:00:43.734 INFO - Shutdown command received
15:00:43.735 INFO - initiating shutdown
15:00:43.735 INFO - Got result: OK on session null
Selenium Standalone has exited with code 0
```

After Selene exits I can then type in repl and enter something which looks like the debug mode, but as it cannot connect to the backend as it's closed now I can no longer perform debug commands.

How do I stop Selenium from crashing?

I've tried updating to the latest

```
webdriver-manager update                                                           
selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.
```

**Update**

Hitting 'd' or 'c' causes selenium to shutdown.

```
Completed 200 OK in 25.4ms (Views: 20.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
press c to continue to the next webdriver command
press d to continue to the next debugger statement
press ^C to exit
-- WebDriver control flow schedule 
 |- waiting for debugger to attach
 |---    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/map7/pais/spec/javascripts/protractor_specs/invoices/create_invoices_spec.js.coffee:17:15)
 |- Protractor.waitForAngular()
 |---    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/map7/pais/spec/javascripts/protractor_specs/invoices/create_invoices_spec.js.coffee:19:20)
 |- Protractor.waitForAngular()
 |---    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/map7/pais/spec/javascripts/protractor_specs/invoices/create_invoices_spec.js.coffee:20:27)
wd-debug> Attempting to shut down selenium nicely
13:36:14.190 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
13:36:14.191 INFO - Command request: shutDownSeleniumServer[, ] on session null
13:36:14.192 INFO - Shutdown command received
13:36:14.193 INFO - initiating shutdown
13:36:14.193 INFO - Got result: OK on session null
Selenium Standalone has exited with code 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I meant 2.1.0

Comment: Are you able to 'c' or 'd' for next debugging statement?

Comment: Hitting 'd' or 'c' causes selenium to shutdown. See the update for more info.